# Select DB Data vs Html Data

Tags: php, html

I have a question about select boxes. when dealing with yes or no values or 1 or 2 or countries.. is it better to use DB or HTML?

if i had 10 countries would it be better to use a db or just select from HTML to send to db?

Comment: You have to put in DB or File if you data's is dynamic data's ,if not , I would prefer put the data's in the code to save DB IO time

Comment: ok let me restate if you have values of yes or no wouldnt it be easier to just put that in html then selete it and send it to db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

A few cases when you should consider keeping the values in a database:

- it's a big list
- your list has other associated data (for example, you want to show a
  list of a few countries, but you also want to maintain related data
  like population or latitude / longitude, etc)
- you expect a list to grow or change
- the values are related to other data in your database (for
  example, when you'd want to create a foreign key on a field in
  another table that should be restricted to your set of values)

If you are dealing with just a simple list of values that won't grow or change, and isn't related to other data, there isn't a reason (other than personal preference or standard protocol) to store it in a database.

---

Regarding the values `Yes` and `No`:  Generally speaking, you would not store these in a database.  One case in which you would store these in a database is if you expect your application will need to support multiple languages.